# How can I query neo4j labels with patterns?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

how can I query on a partial node label?

For instance, if I have nodes whit labels like the following
(n :user:v#1.1.3)
(n :user:v#1.1.4)
(n :user:v#1.1.3.2)
(n :usei:v#1.01.3.3)

how can I ask v > 1.1.3 considering all the subparts as numbers?

return should be the latest 3 node

Thank you

Paolo

Comment: Beware that . and # are invalid characters.

Comment: You can backtick-quote the labels `v#1.1.3` and perhaps use UNION to find all 3.

Comment: You can also create a version-tree to connection your nodes to: `(:Major)<-[:HAS_MAJOR]-(:Minor)<-[:HAS_MINOR]-(:Build)<-[:HAS_VERSION]-(:User)`

Comment: Right about the tickquotes ^^ Nice idea with the version graph.

Comment: Sure, of course I backticked it!

Answer (score 1):

I tried a similar query:

```
CREATE (n:Foo_1_1),(m:Foo_1_2),(p:Foo_1_1_1),(q:Foo_1_2_1)
RETURN n, m, p, q;
```

You could match nodes with this:

```
MATCH n
WITH n,[label IN labels(n)| label =~ 'Foo.*' AND TOINT(REPLACE(REPLACE(label,'Foo_',''), '_', '')) > 11] AS allResults
WHERE ANY (matches IN allResults WHERE matches = TRUE)
RETURN n
```

Here I try matching all labels whose version is strictly larger than Foo_1_1 (which in fact corresponds to 11 [" > 11" part] after the TOINT o REPLACE o REPLACE application).
Then, I return all nodes whose at least 1 label matches based on this little version comparison.

However, I would recommend these labels become regular indexed properties. The previous query would simply become a full-text search on the `Foo_*` properties and would certainly perform much better than this query.

A version graph would also probably a viable alternative, as suggested Michael.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all!

I finally choose to implement as a version graph,as it seems to be the most simple and definitely complete way.

Paolo